# Available Data Extensions in Goal Definition

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, goals

When trying to define Criteria for Goal Definition in Journey Builder, the list of available Data Extensions in **Contact Data** doesn't show the Data Extension I use as Entry Source. Does anyone know the criteria for being available in that list?

I marked the DE as Testable and Sendable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to [add your sendable data extension to your data model in Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_create_an_attribute_group.htm&type=5):

This allows your data extension to be used in the context of 'Contact Data' (distinction between this and journey data below):

[image]

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&type=5

Having your data extension available as Contact Data will allow you to create the goal criteria you need, although be aware that there are some limitations (such as [attribute-to-attribute comparisons](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_attribute_comparison.htm&type=5) cannot be made on nullable data extension fields).